# Acceptable to have list tags within form tags

Tags: html, css

Is there any issue with having list tags within a form?

Here is my code example: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/928Dj/33/

```
<div>
    <ul id="filter">
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any status &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="opt">
            <form>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Active" /></li>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="status" value="Inactive" /></li>
            </form>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown">Any date &#9662;</a>
        <ul class="opt">
            <form>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="Today" /></li>
          <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="This Week" /></li>
            </form>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why don't you put the `ul` tags inside the `form` tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markup in the question is invalid: no version of HTML allows a `form` element as a child of `ul`, or `li` as a child of `form`. It is valid to nest the `ul` inside `form`:

```
  <form> 
     <ul class="opt">
      <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="Today" /></li>
      <li><input class="option" type="submit" name="date" value="This Week" /></li>
    </ul>
  </form>
```

Naturally, the styling and the jQuery code may need to be modified to reflect this structure.

Whether the use of `ul` inside `form` makes sense is a different issue. The is not much point in using a two-item bulleted list and using CSS to make it displayed as if it were not a bulleted list. But it is valid.